# Output of numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I noticed a strange thing concerning the output of numpy.where. According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) the output should be of type ndarray. If I provide all arguments (including also the optional ones) this is true, e.g.

```
np.where(foo == 2, foo, -1)
>>> array([-1,  2, -1, -1])
```

However, if I insert an argument like

```
np.where(foo == 2)
>>> (array([1], dtype=int64),)
```

I get an array encapsulated in a tuple. Does anyone know why that would make any sense?

Comment: That's expected. When you call `np.where` on a single array, it  is equivalent to `np.nonzero`. This is also mentioned in the doc (**Note** part).

Comment: Oops, I must have missed that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation you provided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`.

Looking at `np.nonzero()`'s [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero), we can see that it returns a tuple of arrays.

Comment: Okay, apparently I'm blind :) Thanks a lot!